# How to space two checkboxes with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a bootstrap form page but I suck at frontend.

My question is really simple: how can I space those checkboxes?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Repetir?</label>
    <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
         <label class="form-check-label">Segunda</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
          <label class="form-check-label">Terça</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
          <label class="form-check-label">Quarta</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
          <label class="form-check-label">Quinta</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
          <label class="form-check-label">Sexta</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
          <label class="form-check-label">Sábado</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
          <label class="form-check-label">Domingo</label>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is an image of the result:
[image]

They are very close together. thank you

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You should not give the same id to every checkbox!

Comment: Use margins to add space where you need it.

Comment: @j08691 thank you, I just copied and pasted, I'll fix it.

Comment: @RahulR. 3.3.7 a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use margin left (`ml-x`), margin right (`mr-x`) or padding left (`pl-x`), padding right (`pr-x`) classes of bootstrap-4 or alpha. Where `x` is any number (1, 2, 3 etc).

e.g. pl-1, or pr-2

**[Refer here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)**

With bootstrap-3, you can write your own simple class:

```
.ml-1 {
  margin-left: 4px !important;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, No :(

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd like a custom layout, using grid system should be an option.
Just use .form-row as a replacement of .form-check and wrap your checkboxes into the .

```
<div class="form-group container">

  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda1">
      <label class="form-check-label">Segunda</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda2">
      <label class="form-check-label">Terça</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda3">
      <label class="form-check-label">Quarta</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda4">
      <label class="-form-check-label">Quinta</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda5">
      <label class="form-check-label" style="border:1px">Sexta</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda6">
      <label class="form-check-label">Sábado</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda7">
      <label class="form-check-label">Domingo</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wgyjd9n/

Comment: Not sure what style sheet you are using, but I think in Bootstrap `form-row` should be the class of the outer element and `form-group` is for the inner elements. You used them the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add a m tag and add it in your code after every input type checkbox tag

.css:

```
m { margin:20px }
```

and your rest of the code goes like this:
.html:

```
<div class="form-group container">
        <label for="">Repetir?</label>
        <div class="form-check">

           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Segunda</label>
            <m></m>
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Terça</label>
           <m></m>
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Quarta</label>
           <m></m>
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Quinta</label>
           <m></m>
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Sexta</label>
           <m></m>
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Sábado</label>
           <m></m>
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="segunda">
           <label class="form-check-label">Domingo</label>
           <m></m>
        </div>
    </div>
```

hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to keep them horizontally. You can simply add a right margin to `.form-check-label` like bellow:

```
.form-group .form-check .form-check-label{
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.form-group .form-check .form-check-label:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/odQjbW)